# iptables does not block forwarding to another IP of the host itself

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I have host used as gateway with

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
```

and iptables rpfilter that is used instead

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -m rpfilter --invert -j LOG-DROP-RP
```

My host have 2 interfaces eth1 with IP 10.0.0.1/8 and eth2 with IP 192.168.0.1/16.
If some host with IP 192.168.0.2 on eth**1** send packet it's dropped and logged.
Forwarding table also block forwarding between eth1 and eth2. Packet from 10.0.0.2 on eth**1** to 192.168.0.2 on eth**2** blocked and logged by forwarding rules.

But if host with IP 10.0.0.2 on eth**1** send packet to 192.168.0.1 it will pass. rpfilter just ignores it. Forwarding table seems to be ignored as well.

How do I prevent it? Because there may be some private interface eth3 on this host with private service listening on it and it can be accessed from anywhere which is unwanted.

Comment: When you say "Packet from 10.0.0.2 on eth1 to 192.168.0.2 on eth2 blocked and logged by forwarding rules", is that what you are expecting and what you want?  If yes, can you describe what you mean when you say "I have host used as gateway"?

Comment: yes, that is expected and wanted behavior. Forwarding between eth1 and eth2 should be blocked. Other hosts in network has this host as gateway.

Comment: So you have more interfaces than just eth1 and eth2, and you allow forwarding (ip_forward=1 ; what I'm assuming you mean by gateway) between the other interfaces?

Comment: Yes, ip_forward=1 and there is interface to world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux uses the weak [host model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model): any IP address assigned to any interface belongs to the host as a whole. When you reach from 10.0.0.2 to 192.168.0.1 there's no forwarding involved because the destination address belongs to the host: the packet gets handled by filter/INPUT, not by filter/FORWARD (which thus won't be evaluated for this packet). A detailed schematic of the packet's trip can be found [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg).

This is not a routing anomaly, so this won't trigger [Strict Reverse Path Forwarding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.2), be it set in the [routing stack](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v5.4#n1225) or in *iptables*'s [*rpfilter*](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#rpfilter) module.

So you have to also add explicit rules for this with IP addresses. If still wishing to put this in the *raw* table, the *addrtype* match works even there to figure out if the destination is local (or also broadcast). You can add after the SRPF test these rules (which would work if multiple IP addresses were assigned to the host rather than just the .1 ones):

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 ! -d 10.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL,BROADCAST -j DROP
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/16 ! -d 192.168.0.0/16 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL,BROADCAST -j DROP
```

I wouldn't know with *iptables* how to add generic rules that will not include details related to the specific addresses in use. It's possible with [*nftables*](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/nftables/nft.8#FIB_EXPRESSIONS):

> ```
> # drop packets to address not configured on incoming interface
> filter prerouting fib daddr . iif type != { local, broadcast, multicast } drop
> ```

Comment: While the general statement is accurate, I don't think this relates to the question. Op said their host has 2 addresses: 10.0.0.1/8 and 192.168.0.1/16. The source address 10.0.0.2 would be external from another host.

Comment: it looks like this is what i was looking for. But I have little question when such rules not yet added. Is it possible for bad host 10.0.0.2 to access 127.0.0.1 of router same way as it can access 192.168.0.1?

Comment: It's not possible for two reasons: 1/ the rules I added prevent it: 10.0.0.2 reaching 127.0.0.1 will still match `-s 10.0.0.0/8 ! -d 10.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL,BROADCAST` 2/ but most importantly, without any rule anywhere, it would trip a routing restriction: [`route_localnet`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v5.4#n1220) not enabled, and be dropped anyway.